# In MS Excel 2007, replace numeric value with same value plus function

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

For example, if Column A contains:

```
123
456
789
```

I want to replace values with:

```
=(123/60)
=(456/60)
=(789/60)
```

I know I could create another column to do something similar, but would rather know how to search and replace for this sort of pattern or drag and replace as one can do with other formula cells.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to reference "found" values in the replace box in Excel as you would do with regular expressions. There are plugins for Excel that do this (one example linked below, but there are many). I suggest you create a separate column with the values you want, then copy that column and paste values as needed - or use a plugin.

http://www.mapilab.com/excel/find_and_replace/

Answer (score 0):

Do this in simple way:-

1. In `Column B`, place this formula `="=("&A1&"/60)"` in the `Cell B1`
2. Double Click on **`+`** symbol at bottom right corner of the `Cell B1`
3. Now updated formula is pasted in all cells under `Column B`
4. Copy whole Column B and paste it on `Notepad`
5. Once again select all `CTRL+A` and copy `CTRL+C` the formulas on Notepad
6. Now select the `Cell A1`
7. Paste the formulas

Now you will see all the formulas are updated as you expected in `Column A`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with a paste-special solution.

1. Enter 60 in some cell.
2. Copy that cell.
3. Select the values in `Column A`, right-click, and choose 'Paste Special'.
4. Choose 'Divide' under 'Operations'. Click OK.

If `Column A` holds values, the division will not show up as a formula, but rather as a simple value. E.g., `123` becomes `2.05` rather than `=(123/60)`. However, if `Column A` contains formulas, the formulas will be amended to show the division. E.g., `=SUM(B1:D1)` becomes `=SUM(B1:D1)/60`.